# Retrieve twilio voice logs via webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-api, twilio-node

I've checked the documentation and it explains how to retrieve call logs via API calls, but there does not seem to be a webhook available whenever a log is created :')

Is there an easy way to get notified whenever twilio creates a log for any number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio doesn't have webhooks that are fired on the creation of call logs.

You could however utilise the incoming call & status callback [webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks) on phone numbers within the account to determine when specific actions are fired and begin any actions needed.

Comment: Alternatively, and depending on your use case, perhaps a cron job is more suitable here to scan the call logs and intervals and extract any new data found.

Comment: Another option that may be of interest is Event Streams, but not exactly the CDRs you are looking for (is is that droid?) - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/insights/event-streams#voice-insights-events

Comment: Ah I was not aware of the event streams! Not precisely what I'm looking for, but it's great to know, thank you @Alan! :)